# Hat Dash 2012 - poll

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Mathematica.SE has been given the opportunity to participate in a frivolous levity called [Hat Dash](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/), wherein user avatars are decorated with various hats for different activities:

[image]

Some points from the devs:

1. > This year, we're expanding the promotion to all sites which choose to participate, and redesigning the hat selection to be more appropriate to the entire network (no severed Wampa heads). Some of it is holiday-themed, some of it is a bit silly, and all of it is (hopefully) fun!
2. > Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally  anti-hat will have an "I hate hats" option available, just as we had on Gaming last year.

We will have opted out by default by the 28th of November if the community doesn't request this.

---

Based on the community's feedback, we have notified SE that we'll be opting out of the hat fest. The poll is now closed.

Comment: I don't mind either way, so I don't need to vote. Or I could vote for both.

Comment: I downvoted the question and both answers. I would also downvote this very comment if I could

Comment: @belisarius what does that even mean? :-P

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Perhaps he means this poll was too unimportant to have been asked on meta and distracted his unholiness from [cooking](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=6798953#6798953) [cats](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=6900440#6900440) :D

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I feel that if the OP considers it a _frivolous levity_, the question shouldn't have been posted. Anyway, I reconsidered my downvote for the "No" answer.

Comment: @rm-rf [It isn't me, it's Argentina](http://www.lanacion.com.ar/175163-comen-gatos-la-culpa-es-del-modelo)

Comment: @belisarius As a moderator it is important that I act in the interest of my community and not (primarily) myself, so IMHO it was necessary that I ask this question.  That my personal bias may have leaked into its wording I do not apologize for.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Of course! I'm not downvoting _you_ (neither as a mod, nor as a user). I'm downvoting the _idea_

Comment: @belisarius Down voting the *answer* does disrupt the voting process.  It makes it look like some people are using two votes (one up, one down).  Couldn't you please just keep the downvote on the question in the future?

Comment: @Szabolcs For the purposes of vote counting, you can just ignore the downvotes.

Comment: @rm-rf People who don't have a lot of rep can only see the net vote count, and right now we have -2 on one answer only.  Maybe an "upvote this if you want it, downvote it if you don't want it" kind of asnwer could avoid the problem entirely.

Comment: @Szabolcs I agree; in the future I'll do that, or just word the question so that it is clear what a vote on the question means.  (I didn't do the latter only because I'm not supporting this and I didn't want to have to write my question in that fashion.  In retrospect I could have just put *vote on this question...* in bold at the bottom.)

Comment: @Szabolcs I understand your point. Perhaps a Q&A platform isn't good for polling. I guess the solution is what Mr. suggested in his last comment

Comment: **Note:** The question & answers have been locked merely to preserve the votes as on the day we informed SE (or a day later).

Answer (score 18):

No, please keep Hat Dash off our professional site; it's far too silly!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this looks like fun and I want Hat Dash 2012 on *Mathematica*.SE.